# How to find out how many times 3 values fit into one value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

so I have the following constellation:

There is a total number and I need to find out how many times the value X, Y and Z fit into it.
For example:

Total: 10.000
X: 5000
Y: 3000
Z: 1000

The result should be:
1 times X
1 times Y
2 times Z

how can I calculate that with JS?

```js
if (Total >= X) {
  numberOfX = Math.floor(Total / X);
  if (Total % X !== 0) {
    divisionRest = Total - (X * numberOfX);
    if (divisionRest >= Y) {
      numberOfY = Math.floor(divisionRest / Y)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't x be 2? Last time I checked 10k / 5k = 2. So it would be x: 2, y: 0, z: 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution

You can check how often the value fits in by

- First checking how often the highest value fits in `while(input >= 10000)`. As long as it fits in increment your counter and subtract the value from the input `input -= 10000`.
- Then apply this for your next value.

Because you have multiple values here to check you can use an array.
 Iterate over the array as long the current value fits in subtract it from the input and increment the counter.

When it will not fit in anymore then go to your next value in the array and do the same with it as long as you have values in your array which are not `>=` then your remaining input(After the substractions).

Here is the full code

```js
let values = [10000, 5000, 3000, 1000];

let input = 508000;

let result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  let counter = 0;
  while (input >= values[i]) {
    counter++;
    input -= values[i];


  }
  result.push({
    "number": values[i],
    "counter": counter
  });
}




console.log(result);
```

Comment: Glad that it helped you!:)

Answer (score 0):

I know that there already is an answer, however I wanted to point out that you can do the same thing in a more concise way:

```js
var values = [10000, 5000, 3000, 1000];
var input = 508000;
var result = [];
for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
  var counter = Math.floor(input / values[i]);
  input = input % values[i]
  result.push({
    "number": values[i],
    "counter": counter
  });
}
console.log(result);
```